# How to check whether an option exists for a program in autoconf

Tags: python, pip, autoconf, automake

In particular, my project contains a small piece of python code that I need to use `pip` to install.  My systems are heterogeneous, some have the `pip install --system` option and others don't.  If you use the `--system` option it will crash on system without the `pip install`.  I know for simpler situations I could used `AC_CHECK_PROGRAM([PROG], [prog --optionx], [prog --optionx], [prog])` assuming that option has no argument.  The `pip` is a little bit tricky, it has subprograms like `install`.  If I used the `install` subprogram it will actually try to install something; as expected, it will fail.  I could do something like `pip install --help | grep '\-system'` to figure it out.  Is there a correct way to do it with autoconf and automake?